# How can I use useTheme in Material UI 5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I just started using Material UI 5.0.4 (with `styled-components`), and I wanted to access the theme in a component. I looked online and saw `useTheme`, so I checked the docs and [found it](https://mui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component) - `@mui/styles/useTheme`. However, it was the legacy documentation, and `@mui/styles` does not exist in MUI 5. So, I looked at `@mui/system` instead, and found [the section "Accessing the theme in a component"](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component). However, this just points back to the legacy documentation!

After the docs didn't seem to help me, I decided to use Visual Studio Code's "Quick Fix" feature, where if you hover over the function, VSCode will give you a list of options to import. Here is the list of options I tried, and why they didn't work:

- `@mui/material/styles/useTheme` - Returns the default theme object, no matter what. Looking into the source code, [this is literally what it does](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.4/packages/mui-material/src/styles/useTheme.js) - it switches to the default theme, and then returns the theme.
- `@mui/material/private-theming/useTheme` - This just returns `null`. I feel like I shouldn't be accessing this anyway (it says `private-`), but I tried it anyway.
- `@mui/system/useTheme` - This is what I was hoping would work. However, this is also probably the weirdest one. It gives me the default theme, but it excludes many properties. For example, it only provided `palette.mode`, and there are no other keys under `palette` than that. (You can see the whole thing below)

```json
{
    "breakpoints": {
        "keys": ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl"],
        "values": { "xs": 0, "sm": 600, "md": 900, "lg": 1200, "xl": 1536 },
        "unit": "px"
    },
    "direction": "ltr",
    "components": {},
    "palette": { "mode": "light" },
    "shape": { "borderRadius": 4 }
}
```

- `styled-components/useTheme` - Returns `undefined`.
- `@mui/styled-engine-sc/useTheme` - Returns `undefined`. (I have a feeling this is the same thing as `styled-components/useTheme`.)

Those were all the suggestions that VSCode could give me, apart from things like `@mui/system/useTheme` vs `@mui/system/useTheme/useTheme` (which is the same thing). I also tried googling stuff but it would always be really old, like:

- [Issue #8958 on GitHub for MUI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8958) which references `@material-ui/core/styles` which is v4 and not in v5
- [SO question labelled "access the theme from outside material-ui component"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563267/access-the-theme-from-outside-material-ui-component) which references the legacy docs (`@material-ui/styles` does not exist anymore, and `@mui/material/styles/useTheme` does not work as explained above)

Please, if someone knows, how do you get the theme in a component in MUI 5?

Comment: `@mui/material/styles/useTheme` is the correct one to use. It only returns the default theme if you haven't specified a different one via `@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell But, I have specified a different one with `@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider`... Let me make my question more clear with that. I'll also try to add a MRE

Comment: Here's a simple example showing `useTheme` working: https://codesandbox.io/s/usetheme-example-bbule?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I found the problem - you cannot use `useTheme` in the same component that the `ThemeProvider` is in. Once I made a new component, it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for your example!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out that the correct `useTheme` is `@mui/material/styles/useTheme`, and you cannot use `useTheme` in the same component that you do the `ThemeProvider` in. For example, this:

```
const App = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
            <Box bgcolor={theme.palette.background.default} width={100} height={100} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

Will not work properly. However, this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return <Box bgcolor={theme.palette.background.default} width={100} height={100} />;
};

const App = () => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
        <MyComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```

Will work properly, as `useTheme` is used in a separate component.

Comment: `sx` prop also provides a way to access theme, https://mui.com/system/basics/#theme-getter

Comment: @userharis Yeah, I was using the `useTheme` hook for something that can't use the `sx` prop - this is just an example.

Comment: Technically, you can `useTheme` in the same component as `ThemeProvider`, as long as the component is used in a parent component that wraps it with `ThemeProvider`

Answer (score 8):

For anybody still struggling with this, I got it working by importing `createTheme`, `ThemeProvider` and `useTheme` all directly from `@mui/material`...

**theme.js:**

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

export const theme = createTheme({
    ...
});
```

**_app.tsx (I'm using next.js)**

```
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';

import { theme } from '../theme';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <CssBaseline />
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**navigation.tsx (my component with useTheme)**

```
import { Drawer, useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';

const Navigation = (): JSX.Element => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    const drawerSx = {
        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            background: `linear-gradient(to bottom right, ${theme.palette.primary.main}, ${theme.palette.primary.dark})`,
        },
    };

    return (
        <Drawer sx={drawerSx} variant="permanent">
           ...
        </Drawer>
    );
};

export default Navigation;
```

I was struggling before I did this, it was only applying the default theme, not the custom one.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone wonder why you can't use `useTheme` in the same component as
`ThemeProvider`, it is because `useTheme` has to be in a component wrapped by `ThemeProvider`. The context isn't available to components outside of that component tree.

Comment: Technically, you can `useTheme` in the same component as `ThemeProvider`, as long as the component is used in a parent component that wraps it with `ThemeProvider`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the useTheme from `@mui/material/styles` and is still not working check if you un your AppTheme.jsx (or where you are using the ThemeProvider) check that you are using the ThemeProvider from `@mui/material/styles` and not the ThemeProvider of `@emotion/react`. That why in my case (using MUI v5) useTheme wasn't working with my own theme (in particular with my custom breakpoints).

Comment: Damnnnn thank you. Silly mistake, but with VSCode's automatic imports, it's always pulling from `@emotion/react` instead of MUI.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, your first usage of `useTheme` must be wrapped inside `ThemeProvider` in a parent component.
(`useTheme` needs a theme provider to draw from.)

Technically, you can `useTheme` in the same component as `ThemeProvider`, as long as the component is used in a parent component that wraps it with `ThemeProvider`
Example:

```
const InnerComponent = () => {
  // Use the theme from `App` below
  const appTheme = useTheme();
  // Local Theme. (May want to wrap with `useMemo` too.)
  const innerTheme = createThemeV5(appTheme, {
    // Local theme overrides
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={innerTheme}>
      <Box />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
      <InnerComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```