# How to style a div or span elements in MUI 5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am new to MUI and I have been working a project with dark and light mode. It seems that in MUI components I can use `sx` or `styled` to style thos components, whereas for div I can use `className`. My question is how can I apply the theme changes for div elements? `className` will work for `css` but how can I apply theme? is it possible to apply theme for HTML elements like `div` and `span` in MUI without having it to convert into `styled`? If i convert that into `styled` code gets clumsy.
I know we could use `makeStyles` but that's been marked as legacy so It might drop out in future and I don't want to use that if so.

Comment: You can use "useTheme" from styled package in MUI to apply styling on HTML elements. Check this answer for more understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624210/how-can-i-use-usetheme-in-material-ui-5

Comment: That's for providing the theme, but my question was how to apply theme to a div or span instead of how it can be applied to MUI components like Box. Here do we have to import useTheme and apply conditional classes on HTML elements?

Comment: You can also apply theme on div and span using useTheme method, it will also work HTML elements -     <div style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default, color: theme.palette.text.primary }}> like this, What's the issue than ?

Comment: I heard using inline style is not a good standard that's why. Can I do this - className={`${theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black'}`} ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too :)